# jQuery sorting divs within multiple columns using jQuery sort

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a main list with six columns. Within this columns several rows are there. I want to sort store name and city by using jquery sort. Is there any way to get it to do so? I need to sort city or store name by clicking titles.

### Titles

```
<div class="row storeDetails-heads">
     <div class="col-sm-2"><p class="store-pop-p">Store Name/URL</p></div>
     <div class="col-sm-2"> <p class="store-pop-p">Address</p> </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2"> <p class="store-pop-p">City</p> </div>
</div>
```

### Results

```
<div class="row storeDetails-text">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">Store Name: </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">ABC</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">Address </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">ABC</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">City </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">Alaska</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row storeDetails-text">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">Store Name: </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">XYZ</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">Address </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">BMY</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1" >
           <span class="store-pop-span1">City </span> 
           <span class="store-pop-span2">Newyork</span>
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to sort city and store name by clicking the Titles (store name or city)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** for sorting

```js
$('.storeDetails-heads div p').click(function() {
  // binding event handler to p tag  
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  // getting column index
  $('#values>div').sort(function(a, b) {
    var txt1 = $(a).children('div').eq(index).find('.store-pop-span2').text(),
      // getting value of column for comparing based on clicked p index
      txt2 = $(b).children('div').eq(index).find('.store-pop-span2').text();
      // getting value of column for comparing based on clicked p index
    if (txt1 > txt2)
      return 1;
    if (txt1 < txt2)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }).appendTo('#values');
  // for updating sorted data appending back to dom 
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row storeDetails-heads">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="store-pop-p">Store Name/URL</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="store-pop-p">Address</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <p class="store-pop-p">City</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id=values>

  <div class="row storeDetails-text">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">Store Name: </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">XYZ</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">Address </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">BMY</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">City </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">AaaaNewyork</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row storeDetails-text">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">Store Name: </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">ABC</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">Address </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">ABC</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <p class="store-pop-p2 cnl_1">
        <span class="store-pop-span1">City </span> 
        <span class="store-pop-span2">Alaska</span>
      </p>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MeeraSebastian : glad to help :)